# Using the azapi Network Group Static Members to add multiple members to a Static Group

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am learning Terraform and have been tasked with setting up the Hub and Spoke Network in Azure. I am trying to configure a Network Manager for this task and one of the requirements is to use a Network Group which uses Static Members.

The previous code I was working on made use of a for each statement when setting up the VNets for the SPokes. The network group made use of the for each statement as well.

I have opted for manually setting up the Vnets and Subnets but now I am not sure how to add both Spokes to the same group.

When looking at the basic template from Microsoft I am not sure how to approach adding both to the same Network group. As both VNets are unique, I don't think I can use a for each statement (But I may be completely wrong on this point.

```
resource "azapi_resource" "symbolicname" {
  type = "Microsoft.Network/networkManagers/networkGroups/staticMembers@2022-07-01"
  name = "string"
  parent_id = "string"
  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      resourceId = "string"
    }
  })
}
```

In the above template, I was thinking of using more than one Resource ID but I am not sure it is possible. Would anyone be able to suggest the best method to approach this?

**Old Code**

```
    resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "spokes" {
      for_each            = local.spoke_subnets
      name                = each.key
      resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
      location            = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
      address_space       = each.value.address_space
    }

    resource "azapi_resource" "network_manager" {
      type      = "Microsoft.Network/networkManagers@2022-07-01"
      name      = "networkmanager"
      parent_id = azurerm_resource_group.test.id
      location  = azurerm_resource_group.test.location

      body = jsonencode({
        properties = {
          networkManagerScopeAccesses = [
            "Connectivity",
            "SecurityAdmin"
          ]
          networkManagerScopes = {
            subscriptions = [
              data.azurerm_subscription.current.id
            ]
          }
        }
      })
    }

    resource "azapi_resource" "spoke_group" {
      type      = "Microsoft.Network/networkManagers/networkGroups@2022-07-01"
      name      = "spokes"
      parent_id = azapi_resource.network_manager.id

      body = jsonencode({
        properties = {
          memberType = "VirtualNetwork"
        }
      })
    }

    resource "azapi_resource" "spoke_group_members" {
      type      = "Microsoft.Network/networkManagers/networkGroups/staticMembers@2022-07-01"
      for_each  = azurerm_virtual_network.spokes
      name      = each.value.name
      parent_id = azapi_resource.spoke_group.id

      body = jsonencode({
        properties = {
          resourceId = each.value.id
        }
      })
    }
```

**New Code**

```
    resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vm-spoke-vnet" {
        name                = "ty-vm-spoke-vnet"
        location            = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
        resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
        address_space       = ["10.1.0.0/16"]
    
        tags = {
        environment = "hub-spoke"
        }
    }
    #VNet for AKS Spoke - Not sure if correct
    resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "aks-spoke-vnet" {
        name                = "ty-aks-spoke-vnet"
        location            = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
        resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
        address_space       = ["10.2.0.0/16"]

        tags = {
        environment = "hub-spoke"
        }
    }
    #Subnet for VMs
    resource "azurerm_subnet" "vm-spoke-subnet" {
        name                 = "ty-vm-subnet"
        resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
        virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vm-spoke-vnet.name
        address_prefixes     = ["10.1.0.64/27"]
    }
    #Subnet for AKS - Not sure if correct
    resource "azurerm_subnet" "aks-spoke-subnet" {
        name                 = "ty-aks-subnet"
        resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
        virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.aks-spoke-vnet.name
        address_prefixes     = ["10.2.0.64/27"]
    }
    resource "azapi_resource" "network_manager" {
      type      = "Microsoft.Network/networkManagers@2022-07-01"
      name      = "networkmanager"
      parent_id = azurerm_resource_group.test.id
      location  = azurerm_resource_group.test.location

      body = jsonencode({
        properties = {
          networkManagerScopeAccesses = [
            "Connectivity",
            "SecurityAdmin"
          ]
          networkManagerScopes = {
            subscriptions = [
              data.azurerm_subscription.current.id
            ]
          }
        }
      })
    }
    #Group for all of the Spoke Networks
    resource "azapi_resource" "spoke_group" {
      type      = "Microsoft.Network/networkManagers/networkGroups@2022-07-01"
      name      = "spokes"
      parent_id = azapi_resource.network_manager.id

      body = jsonencode({
        properties = {
          memberType = "VirtualNetwork"
        }
      })
    }

    resource "azapi_resource" "spoke_group_members" {
      type      = "Microsoft.Network/networkManagers/networkGroups/staticMembers@2022-07-01"
      for_each  = azurerm_virtual_network.spokes
      name      = each.value.name
      parent_id = azapi_resource.spoke_group.id

      body = jsonencode({
        properties = {
          resourceId = each.value.id
        }
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code which is provided:

```
 resource "azapi_resource" "network_manager" {
      type      = "Microsoft.Network/networkManagers@2022-07-01"
      name      = "networkmanager"
      parent_id = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.id
      location  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location

      body = jsonencode({
        properties = {
          networkManagerScopeAccesses = [
            "Connectivity",
            "SecurityAdmin"
          ]
          networkManagerScopes = {
            subscriptions = [
              data.azurerm_subscription.current.id
            ]
          }
        }
      })
    }

    resource "azapi_resource" "spoke_group" {
      type      = "Microsoft.Network/networkManagers/networkGroups@2022-07-01"
      name      = "spokes"
      parent_id = azapi_resource.network_manager.id

      body = jsonencode({
        properties = {
           description = "vnm spoke group"
           // memberType = "VirtualNetwork"
        }
      })
    }



resource "azapi_resource" "spoke_group_members" {
  type      = "Microsoft.Network/networkManagers/networkGroups/staticMembers@2022-04-01-preview"
  for_each  = azurerm_virtual_network.spokes
  name      = each.value.name
  parent_id = azapi_resource.spoke_group.id

  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      resourceId = each.value.id
    }
  })
}

resource "azapi_resource" "hub_spoke_configuration" {
  type      = "Microsoft.Network/networkManagers/connectivityConfigurations@2022-04-01-preview"
  name      = "hub-spoke"
  parent_id = azapi_resource.network_manager.id

  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      appliesToGroups = [
        {
          groupConnectivity = "None"
          isGlobal          = "False"
          networkGroupId    = azapi_resource.spoke_group.id
          useHubGateway     = "True"
        }
      ]
      connectivityTopology  = "HubAndSpoke"
      deleteExistingPeering = "True"
      hubs = [
        {
          resourceId   = azurerm_virtual_network.hub.id
          resourceType = "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks"
        }
      ]
      isGlobal = "False"
    }
  })
}



    locals {
  spoke_subnets = {
    "spoke1" = {
      address_space = ["10.11.0.0/16"]
    }
    "spoke2" = {
      address_space = ["10.12.0.0/16"]
    }
  }
}


resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "hub" {
  name                = "hub"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      location  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  address_space       = ["10.10.0.0/16"]

  subnet {
    name           = "GatewaySubnet"
    address_prefix = "10.10.0.0/24"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "spokes" {
  for_each            = local.spoke_subnets
  name                = each.key
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      location  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  address_space       = each.value.address_space
}
```

[image]

Here resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "spokes" is creating two virtual networks , spoke1 and spoke 2 .

Which means two different network groups added to spoke groups itself which is your requirement.

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "spokes" {
  for_each            = local.spoke_subnets
  name                = each.key
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      location  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  address_space       = each.value.address_space
}
```

[image]

[image]

So locals with combined vnets can be made use to add more group members:

```
locals {
  spoke_subnets = {
    "spoke1" = {
      address_space = ["10.11.0.0/16"]
    }
    "spoke2" = {
      address_space = ["10.12.0.0/16"]
    }
    "vm-spoke"={
      address_space=["10.10.0.0/16"]
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, so after some editing, I am able to get the Spoke Subnets to work in reference to the other variables, however I still encounter an issue. In my network interface, it requires the subnet id. 

Bellow is the code I tried

Comment: I tried the following: 
`resource "azurerm_network_interface" "vm-nic" {
    name                 = "ty-vm-nic"
    location             = azurerm_resource_group.test.location
    resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.test.name
    enable_ip_forwarding = true
    ip_configuration {
    name                          = "ty-vm-ip"
   subnet_id                     = local.spoke_subnets.vm-spoke.id
   private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
   }
}`

Comment: The error is as follows: 
 Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 172, in resource "azurerm_network_interface" "vm-nic":
│  172:     subnet_id                     = local.spoke_subnets.vm-spoke.id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ local.spoke_subnets.vm-spoke is object with 1 attribute "address_space"
│
│ This object does not have an attribute named "id".

@kavyaS Any idea how would I go about pulling the ID from the vm-spoke subnet to setup my NIC so I can deploy a VM to test connectivity?